# Android web view is not loading, from asset folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio, iframe, webview

Working normal webpages correctly but,iframes are not loading.

```
W/cr_AwContentsClient: Denied starting an intent without a user gesture, URI 
file:///android_asset/assets/main.html
```

showing this message.

**I tried this**
`view.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true); view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);   view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true); view.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);`
Can you please tell me the solutions ?

Comment: I see non iframe.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/assets/main.html");
```

if the above doesn't work then try this :

```
try {
    AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
    InputStream stream = assetManager.open("main.html");
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
        total.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, total.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
} catch (Exception ex) { 
ex.printStackTrace();
}
```